# Opt-in SMS keyword with AMPScript + Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

Actually what I would like to implement is that whenever a subscriber replies JOIN to the short/long code he/she will be opted-in to all of the keywords under that code.

is that possible? What would be the best approach for this request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to Opt-In for a Keyword.

**Opt-In Keyword via API:**

You can use QueueMO API to add a contact to a particular keyword using ampscript by forming the below body.

```
POST https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/sms/v1/queueMO
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
{
  "mobileNumbers": [
    "15555551212"
  ],
  "shortCode": "Code",
  "messageText": "KEYWORD"
}
```

**Opt-In Via Import Contacts:**

Go to Mobile Studio > Mobile Connect > Add contacts > Import contacts > upload all the contacts > select the Short/long code > Select the keywords > Map the fields.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, triggering a QMO for each keyword would send an individual text for each keyword under the shortcode though.  20 keywords would mean 20 additional texts fired.

Comment: No, it won't trigger an individual text for each keyword when using the above API. If you look at the body of the API, there is no option for you to pass a message. You will only pass mobile number, short/long code & Keyword.

Comment: You don't pass a message through the API, but the actual Opt-In message configured in Mobile Connect for the keyword will send a confirmation text to the subscriber.

Comment: If you configured a keyword for outbound SMS then it won't send a sms. But if you configured a text response keyword then it will send a sms.

Comment: Configuring the message as anything other than a a Mobile Opt-In would not result in the user being opted in.  A Mobile Opt-In message in Mobile Connect requires a confirmation message.  So yes, they would receive a confirmation text for every QMO sent.

Answer (score 2):

I would be concerned about the legal aspect of this, as when someone JOINs a keyword, they are expecting a certain frequency of sms messages.

BUT, I would run an hourly automation that used a SQL activity to find all mobile connect contacts that joined that specific keyword/shortcode in the last hour.  Using the resulting data extension, run the import definition as described by Elliot Harper in this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/136819/54325